# Selectivizr behaviour when both Mootools and jQuery are present

Tags: jquery, mootools, selectivizr

I have a site that has both Mootools and jQuery present. How will selectivizr choose between them? Is there a way of forcing selectivizr to use Mootools?

Comment: I think this answers my question http://groups.google.com/group/ie-css3/browse_thread/thread/df9e3221b9a456be# Selectivizr looks for most compatible library present and uses that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Selectivizr will automatically detect the best JavaScript library for
>   the job. If you're already using a library and it doesn't support the
>   selectors you need - just include another one.

from their website (http://selectivizr.com/) last paragraph first column first block…